# Determine general form of control function andthus show this coul have been achieved earlier

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

Determine the general form of $u_0, u_1 ~\text{and} ~ u_2$ if a system of difference equations of the form

$$x_{n+1} = Ax_n  + Bu_n,$$

where:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  3 & 2 & 2  \\
  -1 & 0 & -1 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}$$

and:

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0  \\
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0
  \end{pmatrix}$$

is to be controlled for $x_0 = 0 ~ to ~ x_3 = [2, 1, 2]^T$ .

Show this target could have been achieved at  $x_2$

Solution
So far I have caculated the controlability matrix to be
$$
C
=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&2&2&6&6\\
0&1&-1&0&-3&-2\\
1&0&1&0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Thus the system is controlable
Now putting Cv=x3 i have the 3 equations
$$
2c+2d+6e+6f=2\\
b-c-3e-2f=1\\
c+e+f=2\\
$$
which i have then put into augmented matrix row echleon form which i have found to be
$$
a-d-2e-3f=1\\
b+d+f=2\\
c+d+3e+3e=1\\
$$

How do I now solve with so many unknowns? also can you please check my working so far is correct. many thanks